# Cross compiling Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx for ARM

Tags: arm, cross-compiling, voice-recognition, cmusphinx, pocketsphinx

I am trying to make Pocketsphinx work on an ARM based processor for hot-word detection. So I am cross-compiling Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx for ARM on a Ubuntu PC. I am able to install Sphinxbase and Pocketsphinx on 64-bit Ubuntu PC and make hot-word detection work correctly using the command:

$**./pocketsphinx_continuous -inmic yes -keyphrase “day” -kws_threshold 20**

But I am getting error log while cross compiling Sphinxbase. I used the following commands for cross compiling Sphinxbase first.

$**./autogen.sh**

$**./configure --host=arm-linux-gnueabihf --build=x86_64-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/rakesh/sphinx –without-python**

Some part of the log for the above command is as follows:

```
checking for pthread_create in -lpthread... yes
checking pulse/pulseaudio.h usability... no
checking pulse/pulseaudio.h presence... no
checking for pulse/pulseaudio.h... no
checking alsa/asoundlib.h usability... yes
checking alsa/asoundlib.h presence... yes
checking for alsa/asoundlib.h... yes
checking for snd_pcm_open in -lasound... no
checking for doxygen... no
```

When I issued the **make** command I am getting the following error log:

```
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_any'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_sizeof'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_channels'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_rate_near'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_nonblock'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_drop'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_close'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_time_near'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_get_buffer_time_max'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_format'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_start'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_strerror'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_access'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_open'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_resume'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_readi'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_prepare'
../../src/libsphinxad/.libs/libsphinxad.so: undefined reference to `snd_pcm_hw_params_set_buffer_time_near'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:413: recipe for target 'sphinx_cont_seg' failed
make[2]: *** [sphinx_cont_seg] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/rakesh/Sphinx/sphinxbase/src/sphinx_adtools'
Makefile:374: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/rakesh/Sphinx/sphinxbase/src'
Makefile:479: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
```

Can someone suggest a solution to resolve the errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to their example Android project at https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android-demo, their prebuilt pocketsphinx library for Android (i.e. ARM) is linked together with sphinxbase, but excluding methods related to accessing audio devices i.e. `ad_open`, `ad_start_rec`, `ad_read`. In other words their prebuilt library requires to feed pocketsphinx with audio samples manually with help of audio library of your choice.
Have a look on what source files are used to create this "combined" version of library at:
https://github.com/cmusphinx/pocketsphinx-android/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

While building sphinxbase, script tries to detect available audio libraries: https://github.com/cmusphinx/sphinxbase/blob/master/configure.ac#L118 You should try to force it to "none" with hope it will still compile.